# How to search and replace dexterity content in Plone using rt.bulkmodify

Tags: python, regex, replace, plone, zope

We are migrating from an old existing static site to Plone 4.3. We have imported several HTML pages from the old site and are now facing 8000+ hard coded links that need to be updated in our Plone system to match our new url standard. These pages are built using a custom dexterity types. We do not want to edit these by hand.

We want to use a bulk modify tool within Plone. We are attempting to use it to replace all of our links using regular expressions. Unfortunately no matter what we search within Plone using this tool it cannot find a single result.

I feel like we are missing a step or are going about this the wrong way.

Is there a procedure we are missing or is there a better way to search & replace our hard coded links in our dexterity type content? We think we may need to somehow index the dexterity content so it can be searchable.

We cannot seem to find documentation on this if it is true.

Here are the references we used to try to get this working:

[Plone.org - rt.bulkmodify](https://plone.org/products/rt.bulkmodify)

[Python - rt.bulkmodify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rt.bulkmodify/0.4.1)

[Plone.org - catalog-indexing-strategies](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/catalog-indexing-strategies.html)

Comment: We are looking into indexing the Dexterity Content Types. One question that never popped up in our results may help us in finding the solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852132/how-do-i-add-keywords-to-searchabletext-for-a-dexterity-content-type

Comment: There's a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521918/automation-tool-for-plone-edition/28535763). Check if it helps you. ;)

Comment: Just checking: did you add your Dexterity content type as a new handler, as documented in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rt.bulkmodify/0.4.1#extending-handled-types ? That is definitely needed before rt.bulkmodify will work on your content type.

Comment: @polyester I will have to check our Plone administrator. He is the one who set this up. The looks of it from the answer I chose, it does not look like we can continue the way we wanted to. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, rt.bulkmodify doesn't support Dexterity right now. You must provide a proper `IBulkModifyContentChanger` adapter.

Here the unreleased version we are developing for plone.app.contenttypes/Plone 5 compatibility (not really tested due to impossibility to make this really work on Plone 5 right now). Should work also for pure dexterity custom types on Plone 4:

```
from ..interfaces import IBulkModifyContentChanger
from zope.interface import implements


class TextContentAdapters(object):
    """This is OK for every know plone.app.contenttypes dexterity item"""

    implements(IBulkModifyContentChanger)

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    def _get_text(self):
        return self._get_utext().encode('utf-8')

    def _set_text(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError("%s doesn't implements setter for 8-bit string" % self.context.portal_type)

    def _get_utext(self):
        text_data = getattr(self.context, 'text', None)
        if text_data:
            return text_data.raw

    def _set_utext(self, text):
        self.context.text = text
        self.context.reindexObject(idxs=['SearchableText'])

    text = property(_get_text, _set_text)
    utext = property(_get_utext, _set_utext)
```

Comment: Thanks! We will attempt to get this to work. Knowing that it isn't supported currently allows us to move on to other ideas we have. We will try this method and see if it helps us.